# How do I change the order of my organizations in Trello?

Tags: trello

I started my Trello account and started adding organizations and boards in a somewhat random way while I was evaluating Trello.

Now that I am committed to Trello, I would like to change the order to one that makes sense to me.

For example, I have an organization for a group of employees working on a task that requires input 2-3 times a year at the top, while an organization that requires weekly—almost-daily—input is buried in the middle.

How do I change this order?

Answer (score 3):

They appear to be ordered alphabetically order by orgname (the shorthand name used in URLs, not the full name, e.g. "fogcreek", not "Fog Creek Software").  You can change the orgnames so that they match the order that you want.  For example, you can make them 1_org1, 2_org9, 3_org2, etc.  Note that the display names don't have to match the org name, so they don't have to have change.

To make this change, go to your Boards page.  Click on "Profile" next to the organization you want to change. If you are an admin of the org, you'll see a "Change Name and Details" button that will let you change the orgname and other details.

Comment: One problem I have with this: It seems, there are boards that have NO organization. Still, those boards show up ON TOP of all boards in the board drop-down on the right-upper navigation on each board. Sucks, because this means I have to link each board to an organization, even if this organization is "me"?!

Comment: If your personal boards are in the way, you always have the option of not having those boards pinned to the header menu (In the board settings menu, just uncheck the Pin to Header Menu option).

Comment: This no longer appears to work. It has to be the "Name" property that actually gets displayed.